# java: how could i reduce if(method1()&&method2()....&&method25())?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, if-statement

I am some what new to programming . I need to write an if condition that checks for the 25 methods , and if all methods are returning true then only control enters into if block .

so i tried like

```
if(meth1()&&meth2()&&meth3()&&meth4() ....... meth25()){

 ..... .....
}
else {
print("in else");
}

boolean meth1(){
    if (valid){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;

}



boolean meth2(){
    if (valid){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;

}

...
...
...

boolean meth25(){
    if (valid){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;

}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

EDIT:
im posting my actual code here .....

```
if(v.isValidRecordType(recordType)&& v.isValidClientReferance(clientReferance)&&     v.isValidInitials(initials) && v.isValidPrefixes(prefixes)&& v.isValidLastname(lastname)&& v.isValidGender(gender)&& v.isValidDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth)
                    && v.isValidStreetName(streetName)&& v.isValidHouseNumber(houseNumber)&& v.isValidHNExtension(hnExtension)&& v.isValidPostalCode(postalCode)&& v.isValidTownName(townName)&& v.isValidTelephone1(telephone1)&& v.isValidTelephone2(telephone2)&& v.isValidEmail(email)

                    && v.isValidPrincipalDebit(principalDebit)&& v.isValidCollectionFee(collectionFee)&& v.isValidAdditionalFees(additionalFees)&& v.isValidTotalDebit(totalDebit)&& v.isValidDateOfInvoice(dateOfInvoice)&& v.isValidActivationDateCollectionFile(activationDateCollectionFile)
                    && v.isValidBranch(branch)&& v.isValidKnownOnAddress(knownOnAddress)&& v.isValidFilters(filters))
                {
                System.out.println("processed");
                continue;
                }
            else{
                System.out.println("in the record having clientReferance :"+clientReferance +"\n");
            }
```

and isValid***** methods look like..

```
public boolean isValidClientReferance(String ClientReferance){
String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*";
    if(ClientReferance.matches(pattern) && mandatory(ClientReferance) ){
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid ClientReferance");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This seems like extremely bad design.

Comment: Show some more context around the problem you're facing, maybe there's a better way but we can't read minds.

Comment: How complicated are the boolean methods? Or are they as you describe?

Comment: Why evaluate 25 conditions in one if statement? Would be interested to see your use case.

Comment: Writing `if (x) return true; else return false;` instead of `return x;` should be classified as misdemeanor, at the very least.

Comment: can i use deligates to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a 25 conditions is itself a bad sign. There is already an advice to group them, and I'd go for it. If you can't, then write something like

```
void allmightyCondition(....) {
    if (!method1()) return false;
    if (!method2()) return false;
    ...
    if (!method25()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

which makes it more readable. It also leaves some place for comments and allows easier condition reordering (which might be useful for speed).

Java lacking functions pointers is a rather good thing (I don't think they're worth it). If you really needed a loop, you could create 25 implementations of [`Predicate`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) and use them. Without JDK8 it's bit verbose. Anyway, *it makes no sense in your example*, use it only when you really need it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not directly related but perhaps you can structure the 25 into groups?

```
group1(){
   return method1() && method2...... method7();
}

..
...
..

if (group1() && group2() && group3()){

}else{

}
```

This would make the code easier to read (as long as you name the `group`s well. This is of course if the methods fit into this style, don't force it.

To blatantly steal an example from a different answer, this can be a group example

```
IsUserValid(){
    return IsNameValid() && IsAddressValid() && IsPhoneNumberValid()..... 
}
```

Comment: +1 for blatantly stealing, which is the sign of a great programmer.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this in C, I'd probably use an array of pointers to functions, and evaluate them in a loop:

```
typedef bool (*func)();

func f[] = {meth1, meth2, meth3, /* ... */, meth25};

bool all_good = true;

for i=0; i<25 && all_good; i++)
    all_good &= f[i]();

if (all_good)
    // ...
else
    // ...
```

Based on the edited question, it might be worth considering another possibility. Instead of structuring it as an `if` at all, you might construct an object from each of the strings, and have that constructor throw if the string doesn't match its requirements. Then you'd end up with something like:

```
try { 
    ClientReference ref = new ClientReference(clientReference);
    Initial i = new Initial(initials);
    // and so on for 23 more...
}
catch(bad_input) {
    System.out.println("in the record having clientReferance :"+clientReferance +"\n");
}
```

Obviously, each of these constructors would call (or contain) code to verify validity, and throw an exception if the input didn't meet the requirements for that type.

[As an aside: `reference` doesn't contain an `a`.]

Comment: c tag has now been removed

Comment: +1 totally the way I would handle this (right *after* I flogged the guy that designed it in the first place). And I didn't think of bitwise-and-assignment; not sure it was intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Would it make any sense in your context to subgroup the tests?  e.g. make 5 functions, one to cover tests 1-5, another for 6-10, etc.  Doesn't need to be exact units of 5, but maybe `isNameValid()` , `isAddressValid()`, `isPasswordValid()` etc.

Comment: Cool, same time same idea

Answer (score 0):

If the only things your methods do is say `if (valid) { return true } else return false;` then you can just use the condition in your big `if` statement ("if valid1 && valid2 && ... && valid25")

Otherwise, you can't really reduce consecutive clauses that are AND'ed together (for which you're using &&). Any shortcuts you could come up with would resolve to what you already have.

Comment: You're using && to "AND" clauses together. Edited my answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no magic for your scenario. you have to re-design your data/execution flow/use cases in such a way that completely decoupled.